# Resharper: Ambiguous Invocation

Tags: c#, resharper, ambiguous, invocation, resharper-8.0

**Using Resharper I get the following message:**

> Ambiguous Invocation﻿Solution ITicket.sln
>       Project ITicket
>         ITicket\frmMainTicket.cs:530 Ambiguous invocation:   void DisableAllFields() (in class frmMainTicket)   void DisableAllFields()
>   (in class frmMainTicket) match

*I am new to coding and could use a little help. If I understand this correctly it is basically saying that I am calling a method and it is unsure what method I should use? I have never used Resharper before. Maybe I am confused on what Ambiguous Invocation is, I have done some research on it though.
Thank you in advance.*

From the code:

```
        private void SetViewForBugnetTicket()
    {
        DisableAllFields();

        btnSendBugnetDev.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Method:

```
        private void DisableAllFields()
    {
        tbSubject.Enabled = false;
        cmbCreatedBy.Enabled = false;
        cmbDepartment.Enabled = false;
        cmbCompany.Enabled = false;
        dtpCreatedOn.Enabled = false;
        dtpAssignedOn.Enabled = false;
        dtpDueDate.Enabled = false;
        cmbAssignedBy.Enabled = false;
        cmbMainTech.Enabled = false;
        cmbStatus.Enabled = false;
        cmbPriority.Enabled = false;
        cmbCategory.Enabled = false;
        cmbTicketType.Enabled = false;
        radBtnNoTraining.Enabled = false;
        radBtnYesTraining.Enabled = false;
        btnAddNoteDev.Enabled = false;
        tbNoteAdd.Enabled = false;
        rtbDescription.Enabled = false;
        tsBtnSaveTicket.Enabled = false;
        btnSetStatus.Enabled = false;
        btnResolve.Enabled = false;
        tbResolution.Enabled = false;
        cmbResolution.Enabled = false;
        btnBrowse.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: It's saying that you have 2 methods with the same name in 2 different classes "void DisableAllFields() (in class frmMainTicket) void DisableAllFields() (in class frmMainTicket) match". There is a method called DisableAllFields in frmMainTicket and in frmMainTicket. I'm confused why it's saying this though because both of those classes have the same name

Comment: Could this happen if there were two `frmMainTicket` classes in different namespaces?

Comment: And is Resharper saying this or are you getting compiler errors?  Resharper tries to preemptively show warnings / errors, but this doesn't always match up with the compiler.  At the end of the day it's only the compiler errors that matter, in so far as generating an exe / dll.

Comment: No compiler errors at all, program works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem. It occurred in R# 9.2 VS2013 and VS2015 w/ VB.net.
We had local variables in a method declared as

```
Dim Yield as Decimal
```

Later, an assignment was made.

```
Yield = CDbl(txtFoo.Text)
```

The fix is to qualify the token which is a reserved keyword with the characters `[` and `]`

```
Dim [Yield] as Decimal
[Yield] = CDbl(txtFoo.Text)
```

Aside: 
Yes. It was actually CDbl. The confusion between Double and Decimal abounds in this codebase. It probably needs to go on daily WTF.