# Why does nameof() give an ambiguous invocation warning in a Linq expression, but not when I use the same value as a string?

Tags: c#, resharper, c#-6.0, fluent-assertions, nameof

I'm getting a compiler warning that started happening when I upgraded to FluentAssertions 4.2.2. In the following code, if I call `EndsWith(nameof(x))`, I get an ambiguous invocation warning. If instead I define `var foo = nameof(x)` and call `EndsWith(foo)`, it compiles cleanly. The code runs ok in both scenarios.

My questions are why is this happening, and is there a workaround other than storing the `nameof()` result in a variable?

```
[Test]
public void TestLastNamesAreSame()
{
    var original = new MyDTO("fred", "jones");
    var expected = new MyDTO("barney", "jones");

    // this gives an Ambiguous invocation warning
    expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(original, o => o
        .Excluding(x => x.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith(nameof(MyDTO.FirstName))));

    // but when I use a variable holding the same value, it works without warning
    const string nameOfFirstNameField = nameof(MyDTO.FirstName);
    expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(original, o => o
        .Excluding(x => x.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith(nameOfFirstNameField)));
}

public class MyDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }

    public MyDTO(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `MyDTO` class? I created a simple class with `LastName` and `FirstName` properties and a constructor, but I couldn't reproduce it. Both worked.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi this turns out to be a (spurious?) Resharper warning, not a compiler warning, so I'm not quite as concerned although it's still annoying. I've edited the question to include the MyDTO class, although you'll likely only see the warning if you're using R#.

Comment: I am using ReSharper 10 and I don't see a warning.

Comment: Although I can see some issues in ReSharper's issue tracker related to `nameof` and false warnings. So probably it was already fixed.

Comment: Thanks for that update @SzabolcsDézsi. I have Resharper 9.2, so that's probably the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that this is a compiler error/warning and not a ReSharper warning?

If it is the former, what is the CSNNNN error/warning number?

Have look at ([Resharper: Ambiguous Invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146175/resharper-ambiguous-invocation))

Comment: I think you're probably right. I'll verify and respond here. Regardless, thanks for the tip.

Comment: As Übercoder suggested, this is a Resharper issue that Szabolcs Dézsi has verified is fixed in Resharper 10.